# OpenLayers with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openlayers, openstreetmap

I'm having trouble with a simple task, add points to a map and connect them with a line. But the coordinate function is not working normally. How could I solve this problem? I have no general representation of how this library work. In details, why line not connect 2 point? And how i can get coordinates from map click event?

```
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import View from 'ol/View';
import MousePosition from 'ol/control/MousePosition';
import { createStringXY } from 'ol/coordinate';
import { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import {defaults as defaultControls} from 'ol/control';
import {Vector as VectorSource} from 'ol/source';
import {Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer} from 'ol/layer';
import {Draw, Modify} from 'ol/interaction';
import "./App.css";
import Feature from 'ol/Feature';
import LineString from 'ol/geom/LineString';

let draw;

const mousePositionControl = new MousePosition({
  coordinateFormat: createStringXY(4),
  projection: 'EPSG:4326',
  // comment the following two lines to have the mouse position
  // be placed within the map.
  className: 'custom-mouse-position',
  target: "",
});

const raster = new TileLayer({
  source: new OSM(),
});

const source = new VectorSource();
const vector = new VectorLayer({
  source: source,
  style: {
    'fill-color': 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
    'stroke-color': '#ffcc33',
    'stroke-width': 2,
    'circle-radius': 7,
    'circle-fill-color': '#ffcc33',
  },
});

const initialMap = {
  simpleMap: new Map({
    controls: defaultControls().extend([mousePositionControl]),
    target: "",
    layers: [raster, vector],
    view: new View({
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 0,
    })
})
};
const modify = new Modify({source: source});


export default class App extends Component {
  
        
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {...initialMap, markers: [], counter: 0}
    this.addInteractions = this.addInteractions.bind(this);
    this.removeInteractions = this.removeInteractions.bind(this);
    this.addMarkers = this.addMarkers.bind(this); 
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.state.simpleMap.setTarget("map-container");  
    this.state.simpleMap.addInteraction(modify);
  }

  addInteractions() {
      draw = new Draw({
        source: source,
        type: "Point",
      });
      this.state.simpleMap.addInteraction(draw);
  }

  addMarkers() {
    this.setState({...this.state, markers: [...this.state?.markers, mousePositionControl.renderedHTML_]});
    console.log(mousePositionControl.renderedHTML_)

    if(this.state.markers.length > 1 && this.state.markers.length % 2 === 0) {
      let coordinates = [[parseFloat(this.state.markers[this.state.counter]), parseFloat(this.state.markers[this.state.counter]?.slice(8))], [parseFloat(this.state.markers[this.state.counter + 1]), parseFloat(this.state.markers[this.state.counter + 1]?.slice(8))]]; 

      console.log(coordinates);

      const layerLines = new VectorLayer({
          source: new VectorSource({
              features: [new Feature({
                  geometry: new LineString(coordinates),
                  name: 'Line'
              })]
          }),
      });
    
      this.state.simpleMap.addLayer(layerLines);
      // this.setState({...this.state, simpleMap: {...this.state.simpleMap, layers: [this.state.simpleMap.layers, layerLines]}});
      this.setState({...this.state, counter: this.state.counter + 2});
      console.log(this.state.counter)
    }
  }

  removeInteractions() {
    this.state.simpleMap.removeInteraction(draw);
    draw = null;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div id="map-container" className="map-container" onClick={() => {if(draw) this.addMarkers()}}/>
        <div className='buttons ol-unselectable ol-control'>
          <button onClick={() => this.addInteractions()}>D</button>
          <button onClick={() => this.removeInteractions()}>C</button>
        </div>
    </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

I've developed some features like a draw button and a draw cancel button, but I'm definitely too far away from my main task.

---

Solved

Comment: I suggest you take a look at https://github.com/mmomtchev/rlayers which allows you to draw a line by adding a React component. I am the author.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I checked this library, but in my opinion, the native library is more efficient than react-OpenLayers

Comment: I have a demo with 4000 features, each one of them being a separate React component and a few million points. If you run into performance issues, I will be glad to hear from you.

Comment: @mmomtchev
I apologize for my harsh words. Most likely, I did not fully understand the issue.

Comment: Nevermind, feel free to check the my React life cycle implementations for inspiration. OpenLayers is very difficult to correctly implement in React and you have to use class components.